# UFW blocking HTTPS although configured to allow that port on

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

Is there a way to disable this specific logging? I searched but found nothing for this. I have the rule enabled to allow HTTPS in and it's showing again. Most of the entries are with RST flag. I have fail2ban enabled which is looking for port scan in ufw.log and I don't want to block some IP's because of this HTTPS block.

```
Dec 16 09:00:04 srv kernel: [] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT= MAC= SRC= DST= LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3493 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Here is a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187993/ufw-occasionally-blocking-https-443-tcp-although-configured-to-allow-that-port/1196520).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to disable this specific logging. In Fail2Ban I added something in the ignoreregex parameter.

My ufw-port-scan.conf filter:

```
[Definition]
failregex = .*\[UFW BLOCK\] IN=.* SRC=<HOST>
ignoreregex = .*\[UFW BLOCK] IN=.* SRC=<HOST> .* DPT=443
```

Now Fail2Ban wil not ban anything with port 443. I hope this can help someone.